# IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource What throws this exception in my SpringBoot RESTweb service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

XML file is required, as the compiler says, even if it's a REST project. I' d like to intercept the "/login" call, first time on Spring Security dependency and no idea on how to handle this error. It says that an error occurs while parsing xml document, but this file doesn't exist on my project.

This is my @Configuration class:

```
import com.example.progettoSERVLETCONSAP.Servlet.CustomDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;

@Configuration
public class DispatcherServletConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath() {
        return () -> "/";
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerMappingIntrospector handlerMappingIntrospector() {
        return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<CustomDispatcherServlet> customDispatcherServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<CustomDispatcherServlet> registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CustomDispatcherServlet(), "/custom/*");
        registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> dispatcherServletRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
        ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(dispatcherServlet, "/");
        registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

This is my Servlet class, `@Component`:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CustomDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, jakarta.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getServletPath().equals("/login")) {
    
            super.service((jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) request, (jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) response);
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the whole thrown error:

```
2024-03-24T09:12:09.019+01:00 ERROR 33204 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/api]    : Servlet.init() for servlet [customDispatcherServletRegistration] threw exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/customDispatcherServletRegistration-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:351) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:319) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:220) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:191) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:713) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:595) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:720) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:808) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:84) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:3250) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:67) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:329) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:237) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:471) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:260) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:205) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.example.progettoSERVLETCONSAP.ProgettoServletconsapApplication.main(ProgettoServletconsapApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/customDispatcherServletRegistration-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:165) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 54 common frames omitted

2024-03-24T09:12:09.023+01:00  WARN 33204 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'
2024-03-24T09:12:09.026+01:00  INFO 33204 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-03-24T09:12:09.028+01:00  INFO 33204 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-03-24T09:12:09.037+01:00  INFO 33204 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-03-24T09:12:09.060+01:00  INFO 33204 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-24T09:12:09.083+01:00 ERROR 33204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:291) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:471) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:260) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:205) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.example.progettoSERVLETCONSAP.ProgettoServletconsapApplication.main(ProgettoServletconsapApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:249) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Servlet [customDispatcherServletRegistration] in web application [/api] threw load() exception
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:89) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:3250) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:67) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:329) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:237) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [customDispatcherServletRegistration] threw exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:808) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:84) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/customDispatcherServletRegistration-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:351) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:319) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:220) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:191) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:713) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:595) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:720) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/customDispatcherServletRegistration-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:165) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Add required file to the specified directory.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: How about you provide *all* of the thrown error?

Comment: If it doesn't work then post the whole XML document to the question.

Comment: @user207421 I modified the question, there it is

Comment: So it now contains `FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/customDispatcherServletRegistration-servlet.xml]`. Seems fairly clear.